# activeClass droppable's option equivalent to sortable [jQueryUI]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In a **draggable-droppable** combination:

while an element is being dragged if we have specified the option `activeClass: "ui-state-hover",` in the droppable section  all the available droppable elements change their background-color and when the element be dropped in any of these their background-color returns to their initial.

How can that be accomplished using the sortable?
As far as i know `activeClass` does not exist in sortable.
So When i start dragging-sorting an element the others of the same class should change background color as a way to show where it should me dropped..

any ideas??thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i finally came up with the solution

Using `start` and `stop` event of **sortable** i solved my task in hand

```
 $("#reportTable").sortable({

        items: 'tr',
        revert: true,
        helper: _$helperValue,
        placeholder: "placeholder",
        containment:"#reportTable",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            cls = ui.helper.attr("class");
            $('tr[class*="' + cls + '"]').addClass('placeholder');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $('tr[class*="' + cls + '"]').removeClass('placeholder');
        }

    }).disableSelection();
```

After i created a class in my css file where i change `background-color`
then each time start event is fired i store the classname of the element which is being crabbed and then i add a **class(*placeholder*)** to  the elements with the same class.

Finally in the stop event i remove the class and its done!!!